# Nested recycler view child not displaying

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, nested

Please note the code is not cleaned up.

fragment

View Fragment

```
class CalendarAgendaFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentCalendarAgendaBinding? = null
    
    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
    
        /** Setting up the root binding and returning it **/
        _binding = FragmentCalendarAgendaBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root
        val mlist : MutableList<CalendarEvent> = emptyList<CalendarEvent>().toMutableList()
        for (i in 1..5) {
            mlist.add(CalendarEvent(
                id=i,
                title="Test $i",
                startYear=2023,
                startMonth=7,
                startWeek=28,
                startDay=11 + i,
                startHour=18,
                startMinute=19,
                endYear=2023,
                endMonth=7,
                endWeek=28,
                endDay=11 + i,
                endHour=20,
                endMinute=16,
                description= "Descriotioun is the thing for id $i"))
        }
        /** Setting up the first recyclerview **/
        val rvAgendaParentAdapter = RvAgendaParentAdapter()
        val recyclerView = binding.rvAgenda
        recyclerView.adapter = rvAgendaParentAdapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
        rvAgendaParentAdapter.setData(mlist)//FIXME: THis is just for testing
        rvAgendaParentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    
        /** Creating the viewmodel **/
        val calendarViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this)[CalendarViewModel::class.java]
    
        /** Display the options menu on the top **/
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    
        return root
    }
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater) //FIXME: DEPRECATED
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.calender_options, menu)
    }
    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

}
```

Parent Adapter

```
package com.example.calendertodo.ui.calendar.recyclerviews

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.calendertodo.R
import com.example.calendertodo.data.datatypes.CalendarEvent
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.Month

class RvAgendaParentAdapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter\<AgendaParentViewHolder\>() {
private var eventsList: List\<List\<CalendarEvent\>\> = emptyList()
private var days = emptyList\<String\>()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): AgendaParentViewHolder {
        return AgendaParentViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
            R.layout.item_agenda_parent, parent, false))
    }
    
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return days.size
    }
    
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: AgendaParentViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.title.text = days[position]
        holder.bind(eventsList[position])
    }
    fun setData(calendarEvents: List<CalendarEvent> ) {
        var index = 0
        val mDay:MutableList<String> = emptyList<String>().toMutableList()
        val mEventsList: MutableList<MutableList<CalendarEvent>> = emptyList<MutableList<CalendarEvent>>().toMutableList()
        var curYear = -1
        var curMonth = -1
        var curDay = -1
        for(event in calendarEvents) {
            /** Check if we are in the correct day **/
            if (curYear == event.startYear &&
                curMonth == event.startMonth &&
                curDay == event.startDay) {
                mEventsList[mEventsList.size-1].add(event)
            } else {
                curYear = event.startYear
                curMonth = event.startMonth
                curDay = event.startDay
                mDay.add("${getWeekdayName(curYear, curMonth, curDay)}, $curDay " +
                        "${getMonthName(curMonth)} $curYear")
                mEventsList.add(emptyList<CalendarEvent>().toMutableList())
                mEventsList[mEventsList.size-1].add(event)
    
            }
        }
        days = mDay
        eventsList = mEventsList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
    private fun getMonthName(monthNumber: Int): String {
        return Month.of(monthNumber).name
    }
    
    private fun getWeekdayName(year:Int, month: Int, day: Int): String {
        val date: LocalDate =  LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
        return date.dayOfWeek.name
    }

}
```

parent viewholder

```
package com.example.calendertodo.ui.calendar.recyclerviews

import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.core.content.ContentProviderCompat.requireContext
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.calendertodo.R
import com.example.calendertodo.data.datatypes.CalendarEvent

class AgendaParentViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
var title: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDayAndDate)
fun bind (events : List\<CalendarEvent\>) {
val rvAgendaChildAdapter = RvAgendaChildAdapter(events)
val recyclerView = itemView.findViewById\<RecyclerView\>(R.id.rvChild)
recyclerView.adapter = rvAgendaChildAdapter
recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(itemView.context)
rvAgendaChildAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
}
```

Child Adapter

```
package com.example.calendertodo.ui.calendar.recyclerviews

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.calendertodo.MainActivity
import com.example.calendertodo.R
import com.example.calendertodo.data.datatypes.CalendarEvent

class RvAgendaChildAdapter(private val eventData: List\<CalendarEvent\>): RecyclerView.Adapter\<AgendaChildViewHolder\>(){
private var events : List\<CalendarEvent\> = emptyList() //Can be done in init block maybe, check that out if we get problems
init {
if (MainActivity.DEBUG) {
println("Generate the calendar Day rv")
println(eventData)
}
this.events = eventData
}
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): AgendaChildViewHolder {
if (MainActivity.DEBUG) {
println("view holder is being created")
}
val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
R.layout.item_agenda_child, parent, false)
return AgendaChildViewHolder(view)
}

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return events.size
    }
    
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: AgendaChildViewHolder, position: Int) {
        println("creating :\n")
        println(events[position])
        holder.title.text = events[position].title
        holder.description.text = events[position].description
        holder.type.text = events[position].type.toString() //TODO : Implement enum
        holder.priority.text = events[position].priority.toString() //TODO : Implement enum
        holder.startTime.text = "${events[position].startHour}:${events[position].startMinute}"
        val diffMins:Int = (events[position].endHour - events[position].startHour) +
                (events[position].endMinute - events[position].startMinute)
        if (diffMins < 60) {
            holder.length.text = diffMins.toString()
        } else {
            holder.length.text = "${diffMins / 60}h${diffMins % 60}m"
        }
        holder.location.text = events[position].location
    }

}
```

child viewholder

```
package com.example.calendertodo.ui.calendar.recyclerviews

import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.calendertodo.R

class AgendaChildViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
var title: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle)
var description: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription)
var type: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvType)
var priority: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPriority)
var startTime: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvStartTime)
var length: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTimeOffset)
var location: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvLocation)
}
```

If I try to just display the child in the fragment recycler view it displays correctly, the child's init is running but the onViewBinding does not run

Thank you, feel free to point out unrelated problems as well

I tried different contexts and different initialization orders, but to no avail, I have also asked chatGPT and searched the web, I rewrote it to follow the structure of most of the online guides to see if it fixes it, I also tried to update the context as much as possible(I will remove it as soon as it is working)